# What arguments are there that, by him who is Logos, life was not - immediately and purposefully - created on earth?

Tags: creation, young-earth-creation, old-earth-creation

> In the beginning was the Logos and the Logos was with God. And the Logos was God ...
>   All things were made by him and without him was not anything made that was made.[John 1:1-3 KJV]

What arguments are there that life on earth was made by any other means than through Him who, from the beginning, is Logos (who is now named Jesus Christ) ?

I mean this question in the context of arguments made by so-called 'old earth' theorists who argue for an evolutionary 'creation' - which is impossible (see below) - rather than an immediate creative act in producing life on earth.

All life on earth is cellular, whether animal or vegetable. Life on earth is a matter of cells, even viruses. The organic molecules within the cell do not occur in nature, nor do they survive in nature (except, interestingly, DNA). These - the most complex molecules found on earth, only occur in living cells, not otherwise.

Experiments with electric discharges (to simulate lightning) in vessels containing inorganic molecules have, arguably, produced only a few of the most simple amino acids.

Calculations (see [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1_KEVaCyaA) produced by eminent scientists) show that the chance occurrence of a single protein (of the more simple kind of structure) would take immeasurably longer than the supposed age of the universe.

The chance occurrence of a single cell is simply impossible, requiring the juxtaposition of a vast array of heterocyclic sugars; all twenty two of the essential amino acids; at least three hundred proteins all folded into exactly the correct three dimensional form to facilitate their own, specific, catalytic task; ribosomes, DNA and RNA.

The DNA would need to be already coded (C,G,A and T) to form a living organism, something that is chemically impossible without the active presence of both ribosomes and messenger RNA.

The energy of the cell is produced by the reaction of ADP (adenodiphosphate) to ATP (adenotriphosphate) which reaction (called the [Krebs cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle) or the Citric Acid Cycle) requires an array of sugars and other organic molecules to be successful.

---

How do evolutionists explain the impossibility of a single cell ever forming by chance, of its own accord - and not by the immediate oversight and the focused attention of the Intelligent and Eternal Creator of all things ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about science/evolution, not Christianity.

Comment: Modern evolutionary (materialistic) science is at a complete loss to explain abiogenesis.  This easily one of the greatest problems - a scientific "theory" with zero theoretical support, zero experimental support and not reproduceable - ie, not really scientific at all!  Further, not only are the odds of this occurring very long, but most of the processes are known to be provably impossible.  In my judgement, the problem of abiogenesis remains one of the great arguments for fiat creation by God.

Comment: Despite the above, this question should probably belong in either science or philosophy SX.

Comment: When you ask "What arguments are there that he who is Logos did not - immediately and purposefully - create life on earth?" do you mean the creation of all life on earth within 6 literal days of 24 earth-hours each? Would this question be aimed at comparing the view of old-earth creationists with the view of new-earth creationists? The Catholic Church view would be of interest, I suspect. If so, then that would be a legitimate question to ask in the Christianity section. If that is your primary question, aimed at Christians, is the last question (aimed at evolutionists) secondary?

Comment: @Lesley Thank you for your comment. I have edited to make it clearer what is the focus of my question.

Comment: Are you basically asking how theistic evolutionists make their argument?

Answer (score 4):

Your main question prompts me to respond quite simply – “There are lots of arguments that life on earth was NOT created deliberately by one called the Logos” (who, the Bible informs us, later became the man Jesus Christ.) That is because many people who try to formulate arguments about life arising on earth make zero mention of even the possibility of a supernatural First Cause. So, every argument devoid of including God would be such an argument as you ask for.

Many people these days express great annoyance at the very idea that this God deliberately created this universe and life in it. I frequent a web-site where there are often vitriolic verbal attacks on all who dare to suggest that God deliberately created life on earth. They claim that evolutionary theory shows there was “no necessity for God”. Those people sometimes present arguments too, but I am not going to repeat them here – they can do that for themselves, should they so wish.

Your additional points are worth commenting on, and here I quote from the book below, written by a scientist who believes God (the Logos) created this universe and all life in it – deliberately.

> When Watson and Crick discovered the structure of DNA in 1953, it was
>   realized that the specification for life is 'written' on huge
>   molecules using an elegant genetic language having an alphabet of just
>   4 'letters'. Yet that is not proof of the existence of an Intelligent
>   Designer of DNA. Here's the proof...
>   Information is stored on DNA
>   molecules, transcribed on to RNA molecules and translated into
>   proteins (the work-horses of the living cell). The processes of
>   storage, transcription and translation closely mimic an advanced human
>   language, involving codes, syntax and semantics.
>   This 'language of
>   God' (as Francis Collins, leader of the Human Genome Project, calls
>   it) is present in all living systems and, without it, no life would be
>   possible. It follows that the essence of life resides not in chemistry
>   but in information and communication - things that can only be the
>   product of intelligence - not chance - and which the hypothesis of God
>   would lead us to expect.  *Who Made God? Searching for a theory of everything,
>   chapter 12, Edgar Andrews (EP Books 2012 Edition)*

I will not go into the matter of "arguments made by so-called 'old earth' theorists who argue for an evolutionary 'creation' - which is impossible (see below) - rather than an immediate creative act in producing life on earth." The time element is a subject in its own right, not least because many 'old earth' supporters do not argue for an evolutionary 'creation'.

That is why my answer to your last question is simply that no explanation for a single cell ever forming by chance can give a satisfactory answer. Life can only arise from the Intelligent and Eternal Creator of all things, who is the source of life.